# Update data in Arrayadapter

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-arrayadapter

i have this problem, i have

```
private ArrayList<CustomItem> items; 
private ArrayAdapter<CustomItem> arrayAdapter;
```

i show the data present in items, this data i see in listview, now i want to update data and see this new data

```
if (!items.isEmpty()) {
    items.clear(); // i clear all data
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // first change
    items = getNewData();// insert new data and work well
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // second change                                      
}
```

in the first change i see the data are cleaned, but in second change i don't see the new data in listview, i check and the item don't empty

i don't know where is the error, can you help me?
best regads 
Antonio

Comment: Are you confident that `getNewData()` is returning a list that contains something?

Comment: Please post getNewData(), also you only need to call `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` once at the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the getNewData() function returns `ArrayList<CustomItem>`, can you change the line:

```
items=getNewData();
```

to

```
items.addAll(getNewData());
```

and see if that works?

Answer (score 18):

This is how I update the Adapter with new data:

```
            if (arrayAdapter == null) {
                arrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), data);
                listview.setAdapter(userAutoCompleteAdapter);
            } else {
                arrayAdapter.clear();
                arrayAdapter.addAll(newData);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Comment: ArrayAdapter.addAll() already calls notifyDataSetChanged(). So you are actually calling notifyDataSetChanged() twice here.

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayList` you created in `Activity` class is an reference variable, which is holding the same reference to the `ArrayList` in your `Adapter` class by passing through the constructor (when you initialize the `Adapter` object).

However, by executing `items = getNewData()`, you're assigning a new reference to the `items` in your `Activity` class, the reference in your `Adapter` class remains the same, thus you see no changes on the screen.

---

It's like this:

personA: the ArrayList object in **Activity** class

personB: the ArrayList object in **Adapter** class

PersonA and personB they are both holding a map of USA (separately), and the screen shows personB's map. Then someone replaces the map of personA with another coutry's map. Guess what, the screen still shows USA map.

---

Instead of changing the reference of `items`, you should use `add()`, `remove()`, `clear()` or `addAll()` to modify the `items`'s data then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.