# Populate ListView from array

Tags: java, android, json

I would like to populate my Listview using a loop, I have recently attempted to populate it in a very inefficient way by making multiple calls for the data from SQL. When I realized just how inefficient it was I began to pull the data from the server in one go by making use of arrays. I am having trouble changing my code for this to work.

What I need to do is find a way of looping through the below array of JSONArrays (Which is not the hard part for me), but to do so I need to have my GetSocietyDataASyncTask return the above array and find a way of passing it to the OnCreate/done method in SocietySearch.java (Alot of the Society objects in my code can be ignored and somehow replaced with List societies)

Now I believe that I have included all of the relevant code but if you need to see anything else please do not hesitate to ask me.

**The data that is received by Java from my database looks like this:**

```
[{"society_id":1,"name":"TestName1","email":"Test@email1","description":"TestDes1"},
{"society_id":2,"name":"TestName2","email":"Test@email2","description":"TestDes2"}]
```

**SocietySearch Class:**

```
public class SocietySearch extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_society_search);


    Society society = new Society(-1, null, null, null);
    ServerRequests serverRequest1 = new ServerRequests(SocietySearch.this);
    serverRequest1.GetSocietyDataAsyncTask(society, new GetSocietyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(final Society returnedSociety) {
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
            List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.add(new ListViewItem() {{
                ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.test;
                Title = returnedSociety.socName;
                Subtitle = returnedSociety.socDes;
            }});
            CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(SocietySearch.this, items);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}


class ListViewItem {
    public int ThumbnailResource;
    public String Title;
    public String Subtitle;
}
```

**Relevant Part Of ServerRequests Class:**

```
public class getSocietyDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Society> {
        Society society;
        GetSocietyCallback societyCallback;

        public getSocietyDataAsyncTask(Society society, GetSocietyCallback societyCallback) {
            this.society = society;
            this.societyCallback = societyCallback;
        }

        @Override
        protected Society doInBackground(Void... params) {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            Society returnedSociety = null;
            List<Society> societies = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "/getsocietydata.php");

                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                con.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                con.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

                con.setRequestMethod("POST");

                con.setDoOutput(true);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Read until there is something available
                    sb.append(line + "\n");     //Read and save line by line
                }
                line = sb.toString();           //Saving complete data received in string

                //Check values received in Logcat
                Log.i("custom_check", "The values received in the store part are as follows:");
                Log.i("custom_check", line);


                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
                if (ja != null && ja.length() == 0) {
                    returnedSociety = null;
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i <ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json = ja.optJSONObject(i);
                        //Storing each Json in a variable
                        int society_id = json.getInt("society_id");
                        String socName = json.getString("name");
                        String socEmail = json.getString("email");
                        String socDes = json.getString("description");
                        returnedSociety = new Society(society_id, socName, socEmail, socDes);
                        societies.add(returnedSociety);
                    }
                    return returnedSociety;
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Sample", "Error has occurred!\n" + e.toString());

            }


            finally {

                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();     //Closing the
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
            return returnedSociety;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Society returnedSociety) {
            super.onPostExecute(returnedSociety);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            societyCallback.done(returnedSociety);
        }
    }
```

**CustomListViewAdapter.java:**

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<SocietySearch.ListViewItem> items;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<SocietySearch.ListViewItem> items) {
        super();

        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size(); // TODO Maybe this can be my sql count?
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        //Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Auto-generated method stub

        ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

        View vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

        ImageView test = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);

        test.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);
        txtTitle.setText(item.Title);
        txtSubTitle.setText(item.Subtitle);


        return vi;
    }
}
```

**ListView Layour file (item_row.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="78dip"
        android:layout_height="78dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-3dip"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgThumbnail"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSubTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgThumbnail"
        android:text="TextView"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Everything looks fine, so what's your problem?

Comment: Well with this code I am able to populate a single entry in the listview but no more than that. It only works for the last entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `ArrayAdapter` and specifically `#notifyDataSetChanged`.  ([notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426)).  You can setup the `ListView` in `#onCreate` like you have and store off a reference to the underlying `Adapter`.  Initially the `Adapter` will be empty, but when data comes in simply add it to the `Adapter` and call `#notifyDataSetChanged` as guided in the example.

Comment: I've just came across the ArrayAdapter and am trying my hand at it right now, not super successful with my skills at this point but hopefully I will get there. Do you think that you would be able to post a bit of code to point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView for general usage and http://stackoverflow.com/a/33890027/608347 for updating the adapter with new data

Comment: Still not having much luck, should I be getting my getSocietyDataAsyncTask to return a Society or a List?

Comment: If your `InputStream` contains multiple Societies then your `doInBackground` should return all of them (so, a `List<Society>`).  Then your `#onPostExecute` should call `arrayAdapter#addAll(listOfSocieties)`

Comment: I would also recommend looking into Guava's `CharStreams#readLines` (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html#readLines(java.lang.Readable)) to ease all that IO handling: `List<String> lines = CharStreams.readLines(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));`.  You can even go a step further and check out using a `LineProcessor` (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html#readLines(java.lang.Readable,%20com.google.common.io.LineProcessor))

Comment: ok so my onPostExecute should be: `protected void onPostExecute(ArrayAdapter societies) {
            super.onPostExecute(societies);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            societyCallback.done(societies);
        }`

Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105736/discussion-between-kmil-and-scotty).

Comment: Hey, did this work out?  Accept if so, otherwise whats up?

Comment: Sorted it about 2 hours ago. I haven't implemented #notifyDataSetChanged now that I come to think of it, though I just made a note on it. Cheers for your help with this though, really appreciate it.